# 80's Science Fiction movie where alien has head cut off

Tags: story-identification

Need help identifying a science fiction movie I believe to be from the 80's.  In the movie, a girl swings a sword at an alien.  The alien starts to laugh, and it is assumed that the swing missed, until his head slowly starts to slide off.

I remember this part of the movie from when I was a kid.  As soon as this scene ended my parents made me change the channel.  It has bothered me for years trying to remember what the movie was.

Comment: Are you sure it was the 80's? Could it have been closer to 2000?

Comment: It was definitely in the 80's, or possibly from the 70's.  I remember that the character's wore a lot of leather, and the whole thing was grundgy if that helps.

Comment: This is sounding more and more like Underworld, but that came out in 2003. : /

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230176/80s-sci-fi-movie-tv-show-where-a-male-character-is-sent-through-a-factory-con (which is newer and has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 13):

This was from Ice Pirates with Robert Urich (1984).  The fight scene you are describing occurred in the bar.   The TV Tropes item below (Action Girl) references Maida, the female protagonist who decapitates the opponent.

[IMDB Ice Pirates](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087451/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

[Wiki Ice Pirates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ice_Pirates)

[TV Tropes Action girl](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheIcePirates?from=Main.TheIcePirates)

[TV Tropes Off with his head](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OffWithHisHead?from=Main.OffWithHerHead)

> In The Ice Pirates, Maida takes a swipe at an attacker, then asks, in a solicitous tone, "Feeling better?" The bad guy appears to be about to nod...and then collapses in two unequal pieces.

Comment: Great movie - has some really funny moments in it. Good find!