# 80s(?) sci-fi movie/TV show where a male character is sent through a factory conveyor belt process that will 'fix' them

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I was watching TV in the 1990's in the UK which was showing either a movie or TV show.

I only remember that in the scene I saw that two characters, where at least one was male, had crashed, or were transported, to an alternative planet/dimension/time period.

In the scene they are 'captured' by a 'strong (Amazonian) woman' trope. They are then sent to the 'factory' here they are 'fixed' along with a large number of other 'natives'. I can't remember if that was mentally or physically. One of the captors leans in to the prisoners just before the process happens and says something like 'we won't actually do it to you, but you have to behave yourselves.'

The whole thing seemed very kitschy, and maybe quite dated. It could have been produced in the 80s, and it might have been in the same style as *Barbarella* and that kind of movies.

I have no real idea about anything else, as I saw this when I was quite young, maybe 5-10, which was also 20 years ago.

Comment: Sounds like you've been watching Futurama

Comment: @Valorum I have been, but it's not that :p

Comment: There was an episode of the modern Outer Limits reboot that had a soldier waking in  the future. The world was run by women, with very few men as they felt the men had been the ones who caused all of the problems of the past. At the end he goes back into stasis because they want to kill him.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is likely [*The Ice Pirates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ice_Pirates) (1984).

From the summary (emphasis mine).

> The film takes place in a distant future where water is so scarce and rationed that it is considered an immensely valuable substance, both as a commodity and as a currency in ice cubes. The Templars of Mithra control the water and they destroy worlds that have natural water, leaving the galaxy virtually dry. Pirates dedicate their lives to raiding ships and looting the ice from the cargo holds to make a living.
>
> Jason is the leader of a band of pirates that raid a Templar cruiser for its ice, and discover the beautiful princess Karina in a stasis pod. He decides to kidnap her, waking her up, and alarming the Templars. Jason and his pirates flee, but are pursued by Templar ships. Jason lets some of his crew, Maida and Zeno, escape while Roscoe stays to help Jason. Both Jason and Roscoe are captured.
>
> During their capture, they meet Killjoy, who has been pretending to be a monk to avoid slavery. **Jason and Roscoe are sentenced to become slaves, a process which includes castration. Roscoe and Jason are spared this fate by the spoiled princess, who has taken an interest in them.** Princess Karina purchases them as her slaves, to work as servants during her party. That evening, they are reunited with Killjoy (disguised as a robot). Jason, Karina, Roscoe, Killjoy and Nanny manage to leave the planet before the Supreme Commander arrives to arrest her.

The conveyor scene:

Afterwards, the eunuchs appear like this:

[image: white-haired men in white leotards on which an ID number is written]

Comment: I think this might be it. I'm going to rent it online and watch tonight to make sure :)